# Selecting surrounding states from a given state

Tags: postgis, query

I have a PostGIS spatial enabled table with the states in the US. How can I write a query selecting all touching states to a named state. Like this :

```
Select * from States Where geom touches (Select geom from States Where name = 'Oklahoma')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
WITH state as (SELECT geom FROM States
 WHERE name = 'Oklahoma'
)
SELECT States.* FROM States,state WHERE ST_Touches(state.geom, States.geom)
```

Comment: For the OP's benefit, the first part of this query ("WITH state as (...)") is called a [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html).